# Coherence triggered event upon creating cache

Tags: events, caching, oracle-coherence

I am developing a web page where server has to send a cache name to the client, when ever a new cache is created using ConfigurableCacheFactory.ensureCache() or CacheService.ensureCache() by any other extend clients.

Will there be any event that I can listen at the server end, which will be triggered after creating a coherence cache in cluster, such that I can listen to that event and send the newly created cache name to the client ? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would start by looking at the LiveEvents feature. For example:

- http://www.slideshare.net/OracleCoherence/coherence-live-events
- http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/api_live_events.htm#COHDG5611
- http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/tutorial/uem.htm#COHTU950
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebEBv817Jn0

However, I don't think that there is an event for a cache being created. You can certainly detect when a cache is created, but it is a relatively low-level capability, e.g. implementing (over-riding) a ConfigurableCacheFactory, or a BackingMapManager, or a Backing Map. All are very advanced. Perhaps there is a simpler approach that you could consider? Like just putting that new cache name somewhere in a registry or a thread-local variable?